# Why my flags "unpin" from the model after 250 frame?

Tags: animation

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rza8Q04bUxc&feature=youtu.be

Here's my animation, I could pin down that this behaviour starts at 250 frame, whereas full animation lasts 1000 frames. What's the cause of it, how can i fix it?

Comment: Check cloth physics Cache. Default setting is a range of frames 1-250. Set it up to 1000